# Distributional solution of differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory

So i am struggling with this problem.

The following DGL is given:

$$ T'' - \  \omega ^{2}  _{0} T =   \delta _{0} $$

So first i have to Fourier transform the equation. Then i get the following:

$$ -\omega^{2}  \widehat{T}  -   \  \omega ^{2}  _{0} \widehat{T} =    \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi } }$$

Then i have this:

$$ \Longrightarrow  \widehat{T} =   - \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi } } \frac{1}{ ( \  \omega ^{2}  _{0}+\omega^{2} ) }  = - \frac{1}{2\omega _{0}} \widehat{g}(\omega)$$

with

$$ g(t)= e^{-\omega_{0}|t|} $$

$$ \widehat{g}(\omega) = \frac{2 \omega_{0}}{ \sqrt{2 \pi } } \frac{1}{\omega ^{2}  _{0} +                 \omega ^{2}} $$

Now i would transform it back:

$$ \Longrightarrow  T =   - \frac{1}{2\omega _{0}}g(t)$$

to solve the equation, but i don't know of this is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $T(t) = -\frac{1}{2\omega_0} e^{-\omega_0|t|}$ we have
$$T'(t) = \frac12 e^{-\omega_0|t|} \operatorname{sign}(t),$$
$$T''(t) = -\frac12 \omega_0 e^{-\omega_0|t|} + (T'(0+)-T'(0-)) \, \delta(t) = -\frac12 \omega_0 e^{-\omega_0|t|} + \delta(t).$$

We therefore have
$$T''(t) - \omega_0^2 T(t) = \left( -\frac12 \omega_0 e^{-\omega_0|t|} + \delta(t) \right) - \omega_0^2 \left( -\frac{1}{2\omega_0} e^{-\omega_0|t|} \right) = \delta(t).$$

Thus $T$ satisfies your differential equation.

There are actually more solutions, but those are not Fourier transformable:
$$T(t) = A e^{\omega_0 t} + B e^{-\omega_0 t} -\frac{1}{2\omega_0} e^{-\omega_0|t|},$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some constants.